# prax on ubuntu machine for RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rack-pow

Has anyone successfully installed and configured 'prax' https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax  ? I have tried configuring it on multiple pc but no success.

There is pow but it works only on OSX. If any other alternative please share.

Comment: Are you trying to install Prax on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

First, install Prax and configure your apps as stated on its GitHub.

To know if actually is working, ping to a desire app.

```
ping myapp.dev
```

It should ping to your loopback (127.0.0.1). If this is not your case, check again.

Then follow this steps:

1) Restart your server

2) Restart your browser. If you are using Chrome, you might need to clear the cache (as stated on: https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax/issues/51 and [Pow domains not loading in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777458/pow-domains-not-loading-in-chrome))

3) Launch the app:

```
http://myapp.dev/
```

It is important that the first time you use the `http://` prefix.

---

If you are using Rails (which server Webrick defaults to port 3000, you should add this port to the URL, (I couldn't figure it out how to avoid this):

```
http://myapp.dev:3000/
```

Comment: Had the same problem with starting rails application using `prax`[my browser points to an nginx start page when i pointed it tp myapp.dev]. It works perfectly after adding port number 3000. But then why did the official github repo tels no need to specify port number and all if we are using `prax`. 
"`Calling myapp.dev and subdomain.myapp.dev with no configuration is simpler than editing your hosts file, starting your applications manually on port 3000, etc.`"

Comment: all lies right? @h.APP.y  and I thought this was similar to Pow

Answer (score -1):

1. check on firefox.I had same problem in chrome, then I switched to firefox and It was working.