# How to use prax in a vagrant environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant

I am using a vagrant environment to do a rails development. I want to use `prax` to set domain like `my_app.dev` on the local environment. But it didn't success.

The Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box      = 'ubuntu/yakkety64' # 16.10
  config.vm.hostname = 'rails-dev-box'

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: 'bootstrap.sh', keep_color: true

  config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
    v.memory = 2048
    v.cpus = 2
  end
end
```

I am sure I linked my project to `.prax/` path:

```
ln -s '/home/ubuntu/my_app' '/home/ubuntu/.prax/my_app'
```

And started the prax:

```
ubuntu    3242  5.5  0.7 208052 15464 ?        Sl   03:14   0:00 ruby /opt/prax/lib/prax/command.rb
```

And start rails server:

```
rails s -b 192.168.50.4
```

But from browser I access:

```
http://my_app.dev:3000
```

It returned nothing.

Comment: what does `ping myapp.dev` show ?

Comment: @TonyVincent When I do `ping my_app.dev` outside the vagrant, it shows: `ping: cannot resolve my_app:dev: Unknown host`. When I do it in the vagrant, it shows: `ping: my_app:dev: Name or service not known`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026826/prax-on-ubuntu-machine-for-ror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let your host know about my_app.dev by editiing your `hosts` file. Edit `/etc/hosts` and add a line

```
192.168.50.4   amerisleep.dev
```